# Does StackExchange.Redis support TransactionScope?

Tags: transactions, redis, transactionscope, stackexchange.redis

StackExchange.Redis [supports transactions](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/wiki/RedisTransactions). Is it possible to use its transactions via TransactionScope?

If not, is there any reason for it? [This old thread](https://code.google.com/p/servicestack/wiki/RedisTransactions) seems to suggest there may have been issues supporting TransactionScope at the time, but I didn't quite understand what they were.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the library does not currently support this - not least because redis *does not support rollback or commit of any kind*. Redis transactions are not like RDBMS transactions.

Comment: But couldn't Redis transactions be interpreted in terms of TransactionScope? Like, on commit, send the EXEC; on rollback, send DISCARD.

Comment: @Gigi well, with SE.Redis multiplexing on the connection, you'd have to not send *anything* until the commit/abort. Yes, I suppose in theory it could be done that way; it does not currently do so.

Answer (score 0):

I am using NServiceKit.Redis, and using TransactionScope. I have tested it, and it appears as it works as it should. I think it's the same for StackExchange, as they are pretty similar. Otherwise consider changing, then you don't have to deal with the maximum client call restriction. At least if you are just testing.